# How do I construct an IAM Role for nodes that have access to the bucket and Security group

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create an IAM role for the cloud formation stack I am creating and I'm having issues. I'm getting malformed Json error on line 14 and im not sure why. Also, I'm not sure if I'm understanding how to assign the IAM role the correct way. I am adding the role to the instance properties for instances.

Also how do I enables ssl termination for ELB's?

```
{
  "Resources": {

      "ElasticSearchRole": {
         "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
         "Properties": {
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
               "Version" : "2012-10-17",
               "Statement": [{
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Principal": {
                     "Service": [ "ec2.amazonaws.com" ]
                  },
                  "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
               }] //this is where im getting the error
            },
            "Path": "/"
         }
      },
      "RolePolicies": {
         "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
         "Properties": {
            "PolicyName": "root",
            "PolicyDocument": {
               "Version" : "2012-10-17",
               "Statement": [{
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": "*",
                  "Resource": "*"
               }]
            },
            "Roles": [{
               "Ref": "RootRole"
            }]
         }
      },

 "ElasticSearchELB" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
      "Properties" : {
        "SecurityGroups": [
          "InstanceGroup",
          "ELBGroup" 
        ],
        "AvailabilityZone" : "us-east-1a",
        "Instances" : [ { "Ref" : "ElasticSearchNode1" },{ "Ref" : "ElasticSearchNode2" } ],
        "Listeners" : [ {
          "LoadBalancerPort" : "80",
          "InstancePort" : [ { "Ref" : "ElasticSearchNode1" },{ "Ref" : "ElasticSearchNode2" } ],
          "Protocol" : "HTTP"
        } ],
        "HealthCheck" : {
          "Target" : { "Fn::Join" : [ "", ["HTTP:8888/", { "Ref" : "ElasticSearchNode1" }, "/"]]},
          "HealthyThreshold" : "3",
          "UnhealthyThreshold" : "5",
          "Interval" : "30",
          "Timeout" : "5"
        },
        "HealthCheck" : {
          "Target" : { "Fn::Join" : [ "", ["HTTP:8888/", { "Ref" : "ElasticSearchNode2" }, "/"]]},
          "HealthyThreshold" : "3",
          "UnhealthyThreshold" : "5",
          "Interval" : "30",
          "Timeout" : "5"
        }
      }
     },
        "ElasticSearchBackups" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "Properties" : {
               "AccessControl" : "PublicRead",

            }
        },
         "ELBGroup" : {
             "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
             "Properties" : {
                 "GroupDescription" : "EC2 Instance access"
             }
         },
         "InstanceGroup" : {
             "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
             "Properties" : {
                 "GroupDescription" : "EC2 Instance access"
             }
         },
         "WebPortELB2Instance" : {
             "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
             "Properties" : {
                 "GroupName" : { "Ref" : "ELBGroup" },
                 "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                 "ToPort" : "80",
                 "FromPort" : "80",
                 "SourceSecurityGroupName" : { "Ref" : "InstanceGroup" }
             }
         },
         "WebPortInstance2ELB" : {
             "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
             "Properties" : {
                 "GroupName" : { "Ref" : "InstanceGroup" },
                 "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                 "ToPort" : "80",
                 "FromPort" : "80",
                 "SourceSecurityGroupName" : { "Ref" : "ELBGroup" }
             }
         },
         "WebPortInstance2ELB" : {
             "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
             "Properties" : {
                 "GroupName" : { "Ref" : "InstanceGroup" },
                 "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                 "ToPort" : "8888",
                 "FromPort" : "8888",
                 "SourceSecurityGroupName" : { "Ref" : "ELBGroup" }
             }
         },
         "WebPortELB2Instance" : {
             "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
             "Properties" : {
                 "GroupName" : { "Ref" : "ELBGroup" },
                 "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                 "ToPort" : "8888",
                 "FromPort" : "8888",
                 "SourceSecurityGroupName" : { "Ref" : "InstanceGroup" }
             }
         },
         "WebPortInstance2ELBSSL" : {
             "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
             "Properties" : {
                 "GroupName" : { "Ref" : "InstanceGroup" },
                 "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                 "ToPort" : "443",
                 "FromPort" : "443",
                 "SourceSecurityGroupName" : { "Ref" : "ELBGroup" }
             }
         },
         "WebPortELB2InstanceSSL" : {
             "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
             "Properties" : {
                 "GroupName" : { "Ref" : "ELBGroup" },
                 "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                 "ToPort" : "443",
                 "FromPort" : "443",
                 "SourceSecurityGroupName" : { "Ref" : "InstanceGroup" }
             }
         },
         "ElasticSearchPort" : {
             "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
             "Properties" : {
                 "GroupName" : { "Ref" : "InstanceGroup" },
                 "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                 "ToPort" : "9300",
                 "FromPort" : "9300",
                 "SourceSecurityGroupName" : { "Ref" : "InstanceGroup" }
             }
         },
         "SSHPort" : {
             "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
             "Properties" : {
                 "GroupName" : { "Ref" : "InstanceGroup" },
                 "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                 "ToPort" : "22",
                 "FromPort" : "22",
                 "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0",
                 "SourceSecurityGroupName" : { "Ref" : "InstanceGroup" }
             }
         },
        "ElasticSearchNode1": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
          "Properties": {
            "ImageId": "m3.medium",
            "InstanceType": "m3.medium",
            "IamInstanceProfile": "base-bootstrap",
            "SecurityGroups": [
              "Instance-Group"
            ],
            "Roles": [ {
               "Ref": "ElasticSearchRole"
            } ],
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1e",
            "KeyName": "bazu2-keypair",
            "UserData": {
              "Fn::Base64": "fqdn:elasticsearchnode1.n.chronotrack.com\nhostname:ElasticSearchNode1\nnode_name:ElasticSearchNode1\nenvironment:dev\nrun_list:recipe[ct-server-base::default]"
            },
            "Tags": [
              {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": "ElasticSearchNode1"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "vol1": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Volume",
          "Properties": {
            "AvailabilityZone": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "ElasticSearchNode1",
                "AvailabilityZone"
              ]
            },
            "Size": "1024",
            "VolumeType": "gp2",
            "Tags": [
              {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": "Storage"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "vol1attach": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment",
          "Properties": {
            "Device": "/dev/sdc1",
            "InstanceId": {
              "Ref": "ElasticSearchNode1"
            },
            "VolumeId": {
              "Ref": "vol1"
            }
          }
        },
        "vol2": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Volume",
          "Properties": {
            "AvailabilityZone": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "ElasticSearchNode1",
                "AvailabilityZone"
              ]
            },
            "Size": "1024",
            "VolumeType": "gp2",
            "Tags": [
              {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": "Storage"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "vol2attach": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment",
          "Properties": {
            "Device": "/dev/sdc2",
            "InstanceId": {
              "Ref": "ElasticSearchNode1"
            },
            "VolumeId": {
              "Ref": "vol2"
            }
          }
        },
        "vol3": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Volume",
          "Properties": {
            "AvailabilityZone": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "ElasticSearchNode1",
                "AvailabilityZone"
              ]
            },
            "Size": "1024",
            "VolumeType": "gp2",
            "Tags": [
              {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": "Storage"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "vol3attach": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment",
          "Properties": {
            "Device": "/dev/sdc3",
            "InstanceId": {
              "Ref": "ElasticSearchNode1"
            },
            "VolumeId": {
              "Ref": "vol3"
            }
          }
        },
        "ElasticSearchNode2": {
              "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
              "Properties": {
                "ImageId": "m3.medium",
                "InstanceType": "m3.medium",
                "IamInstanceProfile": "base-bootstrap",
                "SecurityGroups": [
                  "Instance-Group"
                ],
                "Roles": [ {
                   "Ref": "ElasticSearchRole"
                } ],
                "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1e",
                "KeyName": "bazu2-keypair",
                "UserData": {
                  "Fn::Base64": "fqdn:elasticsearchnode2.n.chronotrack.com\nhostname:ElasticSearchNode2\nnode_name:ElasticSearchNode2\nenvironment:dev\nrun_list:recipe[ct-server-base::default]"
                },
                "Tags": [
                  {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "ElasticSearchNode2"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "vol1": {
              "Type": "AWS::EC2::Volume",
              "Properties": {
                "AvailabilityZone": {
                  "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "ElasticSearchNode2",
                    "AvailabilityZone"
                  ]
                },
                "Size": "1024",
                "VolumeType": "gp2",
                "Tags": [
                  {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "Storage"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "vol1attach": {
              "Type": "AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment",
              "Properties": {
                "Device": "/dev/sdc1",
                "InstanceId": {
                  "Ref": "ElasticSearchNode2"
                },
                "VolumeId": {
                  "Ref": "vol1"
                }
              }
            },
            "vol2": {
              "Type": "AWS::EC2::Volume",
              "Properties": {
                "AvailabilityZone": {
                  "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "ElasticSearchNode2",
                    "AvailabilityZone"
                  ]
                },
                "Size": "1024",
                "VolumeType": "gp2",
                "Tags": [
                  {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "Storage"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "vol2attach": {
              "Type": "AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment",
              "Properties": {
                "Device": "/dev/sdc2",
                "InstanceId": {
                  "Ref": "ElasticSearchNode2"
                },
                "VolumeId": {
                  "Ref": "vol2"
                }
              }
            },
            "vol3": {
              "Type": "AWS::EC2::Volume",
              "Properties": {
                "AvailabilityZone": {
                  "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "ElasticSearchNode2",
                    "AvailabilityZone"
                  ]
                },
                "Size": "1024",
                "VolumeType": "gp2",
                "Tags": [
                  {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "Storage"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "vol3attach": {
              "Type": "AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment",
              "Properties": {
                "Device": "/dev/sdc3",
                "InstanceId": {
                  "Ref": "ElasticSearchNode2"
                },
                "VolumeId": {
                  "Ref": "vol3"
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't want the "RootRole" in there, at least - your role is called "ElasticSearchRole".

Comment: ya my bad i repasted it from amazon and for got to check it.

Comment: again, can you please [simplify the code to give a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? 400 lines of code is a lot to wade through.